# is there some way to get all the invalid locators in selenium automation?

Tags: selenium, automation

I have many locators and if any one among them fails the program fails, We can not get a list of locators failed.

is there some way/method to get all the invalid locators in selenium automation???

Comment: Please edit your question with all details such as provide steps and web page URL, elements and what did you try in code also what is error you are getting #

Comment: @JustinLambert it is a general question, if there is some way to get all the invalid locators first even before one fails and stops the program run.

Comment: No there is no way to get invalid locators from website via selenium

Comment: You will get invalid locators error when web element does not found in web page

Answer (score 0):

**The easy way** (in case of you're using a framework and the code is well structured) :

Add the action performed on any locator into a try-catch block and store locator's name into a file, log it into console etc (it's up to you). In this way, you can follow up and update them after.

**The manual way:**
Go manually trough all your locators and look after them in HTML code in browser's console

**The less painful manual way:**
Execute all tests, and from your report (if you're using any reporting tool) or from console, collect and check each locator .

Now, if you're just doing a clean-up, I recommend the first approach. If you're facing issues with the locators, flaky situations, I recommend creating dynamic locators (xpath or css).